# Using Mockito to test Java Hbase API

Tags: unit-testing, junit, hbase, mockito

This is the method that I am testing. This method gets some Bytes from a Hbase Database based on an specific id, in this case called dtmid. The reason I why I want to return  some specific values is because I realized that there is no way to know  if an id will always be in Hbase. Also, the column Family and column name could change.

```
@Override
   public void execute(Tuple tuple, BasicOutputCollector collector) {
      try {
        if (tuple.size() > 0) {
            Long dtmid = tuple.getLong(0);

            byte[] rowKey = HBaseRowKeyDistributor.getDistributedKey(dtmid);
            Get get = new Get(rowKey);
            get.addFamily("a".getBytes());
            Result result = table.get(get);
            byte[] bidUser = result.getValue("a".getBytes(),
                    "co_created_5076".getBytes());
            collector.emit(new Values(dtmid, bidUser));
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

On my main class when this method is called I want to return a specific value. The method should return some bytes.

```
    byte[] bidUser = result.getValue("a".getBytes(),
                    "co_created_5076".getBytes());
```

This is what I have on my Unit Test.

```
   @Test
   public void testExecute() throws IOException {
      long dtmId = 350000000770902930L;
      final byte[] COL_FAMILY = "a".getBytes();
      final byte[] COL_QUALIFIER = "co_created_5076".getBytes();

      //setting a key value pair to put in result
      List<KeyValue> kvs = new ArrayList<KeyValue>();
      kvs.add(new KeyValue("--350000000770902930".getBytes(), COL_FAMILY, COL_QUALIFIER, Bytes.toBytes("ExpedtedBytes")));
      // I create an Instance of result
      Result result = new Result(kvs);

      // A mock tuple with a single dtmid
      Tuple tuple = mock(Tuple.class);
      bolt.table = mock(HTable.class);
      Result mcResult = mock(Result.class);
      when(tuple.size()).thenReturn(1);
      when(tuple.getLong(0)).thenReturn(dtmId);
      when(bolt.table.get(any(Get.class))).thenReturn(result);
      when(mcResult.getValue(any(byte[].class), any(byte[].class))).thenReturn(Bytes.toBytes("Bytes"));

      BasicOutputCollector collector = mock(BasicOutputCollector.class);

      // Execute the bolt.
      bolt.execute(tuple, collector);


      ArgumentCaptor<Values> valuesArg = ArgumentCaptor
            .forClass(Values.class);
      verify(collector).emit(valuesArg.capture());

      Values d = valuesArg.getValue();
      //casting this object in to a byteArray.
      byte[] i = (byte[]) d.get(1);

      assertEquals(dtmId, d.get(0));
   }
```

I am using this down here to return my bytes.For some reason is not working.

```
  when(mcResult.getValue(any(byte[].class), any(byte[].class))).thenReturn(Bytes
        .toBytes("myBytes"));
```

For  some reason when I capture the values, I still get the bytes that I specified here:

```
  List<KeyValue> kvs = new ArrayList<KeyValue>();
    kvs.add(new KeyValue("--350000000770902930".getBytes(),COL_FAMILY,       COL_QUALIFIER, Bytes
            .toBytes("ExpedtedBytes")));
    Result result = new Result(kvs);
```

Comment: How is mcResult used?  I see that it is created and mocked, but I don't see it used again.  Is some method suppose to return it?

Comment: @JoseMartinez I use it to mock Result from the main class. So when this result.getValue("a".getBytes(),"co_created_5076".getBytes()); is called in my main class I can return the bytes I desire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about replacing

```
when(bolt.table.get(any(Get.class))).thenReturn(result);
```

with...

```
when(bolt.table.get(any(Get.class))).thenReturn(mcResult);
```

Comment: Thank you very very much.  You saved my life. I am new to Mockito and I guess I need to do more reading.  The main problem was that I was creating an result for not reason when I could have just used a mocked one. Result result = new Result(kvs);. Again, Thank you